# Tests relying on tables being present

Tags: database, unit-testing, testing, tdd

Is it acceptable for a unit test to assume a database table is present?

For instance if one has a UserStore class and associated UserStoreTest test class. Suppose this class is part of a system that when installed has an "instance" of the table this class needs named foo_users. Is it then acceptable for the UserStoreTest to assume this table is there and use it? It seems better to require the UserStoreTest class to setup the table itself and not depend on the state of the system, which is rather global. Is the former approach acceptable though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is probably to figure out a way to mock your database rather than being actually connected to a real database. There is some overhead in maintaining a mock of a database, but there are numerous advantages.

- Talking to a real database may make your unit tests unnecessarily slow, especially if you go down the "set up the connection to the database and then set up the table for every test" route.
- As I think you've already realized, your unit tests might end up depending on volatile data which could adversely affect the testing process because it is not under the control of the test suite.
- Unit tests can be run on a machine without access to the database. This means your unit tests can't accidentally break the database or anything like that.
- probably some other reasons too

If mocking your database connection is unfeasible, a good middle ground might be to have a test database that is separate from your real/production database. This way, you can avoid worries related to connecting the test suite to the real database while retaining full control of the database for testing purposes.